# SQL - how to create multi row results with no source table

Tags: sql

In standard SQL, is there a way to say:

```
select mubmle as x from mumblemmble
```

And get more than one line of results, like this

```
 x
 _ 
 1
 2
 3
```

without creating temporary tables?  I can do it in SQL Server using row_count() if I know some table that has enough rows, like:

```
  select row_number() over (order by x.SomeColumn) from 
(select top 24 SomeColumn from TableThatHasAtLeast24Rows) x
```

But wonder if there's a standard (less dumb) way to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no standard way, and no way at all in `MySQL`.

In `Oracle`:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    dual
CONNECT BY
        level < n
```

In `MS SQL`:

```
WITH hier(row) AS
        (
        SELECT  1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  row + 1
        FROM    hier
        WHERE   row < n
        )
SELECT  *
FROM    hier
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

In `PostgreSQL`:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    generate_series (1, n)
```

Note that `MS SQL`, unlike `Oracle`, cannot swap recursion stack into temporary tablespace, so you may experience troubles when generating large datasets.

See [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701444/how-do-i-make-a-row-generator-in-mysql/707845) for more details

Comment: For MS SQL, you can use the option MAXRECURSION to change it from to may 32767 or infinite (0)

Answer (score 1):

The SQL 2003 standard defines a way to do it - not all DBMS implement it, though:

```
<table value constructor> ::= VALUES <row value expression list>

<row value expression list> ::= <table row value expression>
                            [ { <comma> <table row value expression> }... ]

<row value expression> ::= 
         <row value special case>
     |   <explicit row value constructor>

<table row value expression> ::= 
         <row value special case>
     |   <row value constructor>
```

And, after wading through much other BNF, you can find:

```
<explicit row value constructor> ::= 
         <left paren> <row value constructor element> <comma>
                      <row value constructor element list> <right paren>
     |   ROW <left paren> <row value constructor element list> <right paren>
     |   <row subquery>

<row value constructor element list> ::= 
     <row value constructor element>
     [ { <comma> <row value constructor element> }... ]

<row value constructor element> ::= <value expression>
```

Which, when translated, means that in some contexts, you can use:

```
 VALUES (v1a, v1b, v1c), (v2a, v2b, v2c)
```

to create a table value with two rows and three columns in each row.  The INSERT statement is one place you can use the construct.  Another is in the FROM clause of a SELECT statement, though showing enough BNF to connect the dots would take more space than SO encourages for an answer.