# Grouping records hour by hour or day by day and filling gaps with zero or null in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, group-by, hour

I have written a query that counts records hour by hour:

```
select TO_CHAR(copied_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24'),count(*) from req group by
TO_CHAR(copied_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24');
```

the result is:

```
2012-02-22 13    2280
2012-02-22 15    1250
2012-02-22 16    1245
2012-02-22 19    1258
```

But I need a result like this:

```
2012-02-22 13    2280
2012-02-22 14    0
2012-02-22 15    1250
2012-02-22 16    1245
2012-02-22 17    0
2012-02-22 18    0
2012-02-22 19    1258
```

Also I have these queries that group by day and month too!

```
select TO_CHAR(copied_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD'),count(*)  from req
group by TO_CHAR(copied_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD');

select TO_CHAR(copied_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM'),count(*)  from req
group by TO_CHAR(copied_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM');
```

I need their gaps to be filled with zero or null too.
Any help is really appreciated.

Note:
There is an answer for this question in oracle using `CONNECT BY` but i need the answer in Mysql because Mysql does not support `CONNECT BY`.
[Here is the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10798905/grouping-records-hour-by-hour-or-day-by-day-and-filling-gaps-with-zero-or-null)

Comment: Does the table have `24` records per day, representing each hour of the day?

Comment: No actually, it can have more records. maybe 5 or more records per second!

Comment: The only purpose of the `CONNECT BY` and `LEVEL` in the referenced question is to generate rows. It is an idiom in Oracle which should have an equivalent in Mysql which does the same thing. Perhaps this would help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806484/generate-many-rows-with-mysql

Comment: I saw your reference. but I could not generate rows with dates, as their data! if I could generate a date range using the method mentioned in your link, I think I could handle that.

Comment: If you need an answer in MySQL, why do you insist on the `oracle` tag? (You put it back after it was removed.)

Comment: @Andriy Because this way oracle tags followers will be informed too. They are sql experts and might have a workaround on this issue without `connect by`.

Comment: @Heidarzadeh You might have just insulted a few non-Oracle SQL experts out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a table called TBL_NUMBERS

```
CREATE TABLE `TBL_NUMBER` (`n` int(11) NOT NULL)
```

and inserted records from 1 to 1000.
Now I can generate any kind of date range using this query:

```
SELECT '2012-06-21' + INTERVAL n-1 [DAY | HOUR | MINUTE] or as dateRange
 FROM TBL_NUMBER
WHERE '2012-06-21' + INTERVAL n-1 [DAY | HOUR | MINUTE] <= '2012-06-23';
```

Then I can join this table with my results to fill the date gap.
If i need more than 1000 date range I can insert more records in `TBL_NUMBER`

If you have any better idea, I'm eager to know that ;)

Answer (score 2):

Generate a single-column `dates_hours` table which contains all dates and hours within a reasonable range (e.g. from 1900 to 2200).
Then do a `LEFT JOIN` from this table to your current query.

For this technique to perform correctly, you will probably need to add an indexed column to your table which contains a converted time stamp (your `copied_timestamp` converted to `DATETIME`, rounded to the hour)

```sql
SELECT date_hour, count(req.converted_timestamp)
FROM
    dates_hours 
    LEFT JOIN req ON req.converted_timestamp = dates_hours.date_hour
WHERE date_hour
    BETWEEN (SELECT MIN(req.converted_timestamp) FROM req)
    AND (SELECT MAX(req.converted_timestamp) FROM req)
GROUP BY date_hour
```

To generate the `dates_hours` table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dates_hours (date_hour DATETIME PRIMARY KEY);

DELIMITER $$$
CREATE PROCEDURE generate_dates_hours (to_date DATETIME)
BEGIN

    DECLARE start_date DATETIME;
    DECLARE inc INT;

    SELECT MAX(date_hour) INTO start_date FROM dates_hours;
    IF start_date IS NULL THEN
        SET start_date = '1900-01-01';
    END IF;
    SET inc = 1;
    WHILE start_date + INTERVAL inc HOUR  <= to_date DO
        INSERT INTO dates_hours VALUE (start_date + INTERVAL inc HOUR);
        SET inc = inc +1;
    END WHILE;

END $$$
DELIMITER ;

CALL generate_dates_hours('2200-01-01');
```

Okay, now that I am proof-reading myself, I realise this is quite far-fetched a solution. I hope someone comes up with a more elegant one.

Comment: Thanks Yak. this solves the problem but for my usecase it is a little hard to maintain the code. I have found another solution and post it here. eager to know your idea.