# Group record by hour in Enity Framwork and fill gaps

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

There was a similar question before [Grouping records hour by hour or day by day and filling gaps with zero or null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10798905/grouping-records-hour-by-hour-or-day-by-day-and-filling-gaps-with-zero-or-null) and [Grouping records hour by hour or day by day and filling gaps with zero or null in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11274335/grouping-records-hour-by-hour-or-day-by-day-and-filling-gaps-with-zero-or-null-i) but both solutuion use SQL. I would like to resolve this problem with code.

The easiest solution is to run:

```
var q = from i in XXX.Table
    let dt = p.Date
    group i by new { y = dt.Year, m = dt.Month, d = dt.Day, h = dt.Hour}
    select g;
```

but I have got a lot of gaps still to fill.

Comment: Is this query going to be composed into another query, or can we assume this (and the filled-in gaps) are going to be materialized?  In other words, does the server have to generate the fills?

Comment: Your entity framework can translate `p.Date` into SQL?

Comment: @casperOne I like to use this query as sub-query so the answer is yes the server should generate the fills

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy I think yes. I never had problems with EF + SQL Server in `DateTime` type

Comment: @Garath that probably was LINQ to SQL. EF will fail translating Date property retrieving

Comment: You can use EntityFunctions.TruncateTime or DbFunctions.TruncateTime if you are on EF6.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy You are right, I wrote this code without checking:)

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ group by date - include empty days WITHOUT using join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17086120/linq-group-by-date-include-empty-days-without-using-join), except that your post is about hours.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch groups from server and fill gaps on client:

```
var startDate = new DateTime(2014, 1, 2);
var endDate = new DateTime(2014, 1, 3);

var dict = (from c in YourTable
  where c.YourDate >= startDate && c.YourDate <= endDate 
  let hours = DbFunctions.DiffHours(startDate, c.YourDate)
  group c by hours into g 
  select new {Hour = g.Key, Count = g.Count()}).ToDictionary(r => r.Hour.Value, r => r.Count);

var result = Enumerable.Range(0, (int)(endDate - startDate).TotalHours).Select(h => new {Date = startDate.AddHours(h), Count = dict.ContainsKey(h) ? dict[h] : 0});
```