# SQL select generator

Tags: mysql, sql, generator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [generate an integer sequence in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304461/generate-an-integer-sequence-in-mysql)
>   [generate many rows with mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806484/generate-many-rows-with-mysql)

Is there a (simple) mean to create an sql request that return integers between 1 and N ?
( like a range(n) in python. )

Something like :

```
select i 
FROM all_ints_values  
where i >= 1 and i < N;
```

where table `all_ints_values` should contains all ints values !!

Of course it souldn't be possible  to create such a table. (and even if N is limited I don't want do this)

**Context :**

I've got a table with sales ( dated by year and month).
I want to retrieve the sum of sales by year and mounth.
You can do that with a `group by` close :

```
select year,month, sum(money) from my_table group by year,month order by year,month
```

But with this I get 'holes' in my list ( if there is no sales in January 2011) so it not suitable to make a graph.

With the generator I could use  an OUTER JOIN some thing like:

```
select y.i,m.i, nvl(sum_money,0) LEFT OUTER JOIN mysummaryview ON y.year = year and m.month = month FROM (select int from 1990 to 2012) y , (select int from 1 to 12) m order by y.i,m.i
```

Comment: Use the mysql's `BETWEEN` clause.

Comment: Could you provide some context of the end goal that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I guess you mean something like the Postgres [`generate_series`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-srf.html) function to generate a numbers table dynamically.

Comment: Postgres generates_series  is exactly what I am looking for. ( but for mysql)

Comment: @user1129519, as the linked questions and the questions found by this search `[mysql] row generator` say, MySQL is the only major RDBMS which does not have an easy method of doing this...