# Number Sequence in MySQL

Tags: python, sql, mysql, sequence, xrange

In Python if I wanted a sequence from 0 - 9 (inclusive) I would use xrange(0,10) . Is there a way I can do this in MySQL?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make a row generator in mysql.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701444/how-do-i-make-a-row-generator-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2):

Since there is no such thing as xrange, one could use a separate table stored with integer (as previously answered), or just make a stored procedure to do the job:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS xrange;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE xrange(x INT, y INT)
BEGIN
  DECLARE i INT DEFAULT x;
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE xrange_tmp (c1 INT);
  WHILE i < y DO
    INSERT INTO xrange_tmp VALUES (i);
    SET i = i + 1;
  END WHILE;
END;
//
```

Usage:

```
CALL xrange(-2,10);
SELECT c1 FROM xrange_tmp;
DROP TABLE xrange_tmp;
```

The above is obviously going to be slower than creating a ready table with integers. It's more flexible though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LAST_INSERT_ID() to simulate sequences in MySQL.

> If expr is given as an argument to
>   LAST_INSERT_ID(), the value of the
>   argument is returned by the function
>   and is remembered as the next value to
>   be returned by LAST_INSERT_ID(). This
>   can be used to simulate sequences:
>
> Create a table to hold the sequence
>   counter and initialize it:

```
CREATE TABLE sequence (id INT NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO sequence VALUES (0);
```

> Use the table to generate sequence numbers like this:

```
  UPDATE sequence SET id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id+1);
  SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

> The UPDATE statement increments the
>   sequence counter and causes the
>
> > next call to LAST_INSERT_ID() to
> >     return the updated value. The SELECT
> >     statement retrieves that value. The
> >     mysql_insert_id() C API function can
> >     also be used to get the value. See
> >     Section 21.9.3.37,
> >     “mysql_insert_id()”.

Read up more [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-functions.html) as well as some discussion on it [here](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?61,143867,143867)

Comment: Hi NebuSoft, thanks for your answer.

I remember something from my Postgresql days that would do it. I would have something along the lines of:

select x from xrange(0, 10); 

Are you not aware of there being anything like this in MySQL?

Comment: I haven't come across anything like that in MySQL. That being said, the examples I provided are straight from the MySQL official website/documentation. So if there was a better way I would suspect they'd have mentioned it when they give examples of how to create sequences in the method I provided.

Answer (score 0):

Try an [integers table](http://searchoracle.techtarget.com/answer/The-integers-table) variant.  This one is taken from [Xaprb](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2005/12/07/the-integers-table/):

```
create table integers(i int unsigned not null);
insert into integers(i) values (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9);

select (hundreds.i * 100) + (tens.i * 10) + units.i as iii
from integers as units
    cross join integers as tens
    cross join integers as hundreds;
```

If you made that last `select` a view named, say, `xrange999`, then you can simply:

```
SELECT iii FROM xrange999 WHERE iii BETWEEN 0 AND 9
```

(of course, you can do that with just the ten-row `integers` table, but I find a thousand integers a little more useful.)

Answer (score 0):

If Python is your programming language, you can map that same Python range to create an INSERT statement of the form:

```
INSERT INTO Table (IDCol) VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9)
```

Not exactly what you asked for, but a single line of Python code that will handle any range up to the maximum length of a MySQL statement.