# SQL, counting from 0 to 10

Tags: sql, mysql

it may sound stupid, but i want to know how (if possible) to count from 0 to 10 by a sql command. i mean i want a sql query which produces one column consisting of numbers from 0 to 10, like this:

0 
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

i'm currently using MySQL 5.0

Comment: Any particular SQL dialect or RDBMS?

Comment: See [Number Sequence in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2495487/number-sequence-in-mysql)

Comment: @egrunin, that's the same thing the prior question is doing.  The only real difference is that uses 0-9 as an example.

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen: ah, I hadn't seen the answer from @geertjanvdk, which does address the problem. I'll give it a +1 so it rises to the top :)

Answer (score 4):

If you simply want the *exact* values 0 through 10, then the following will work in all DBMS:

```
Select Num
From    (
        Select 0 As Num
        Union All Select 1
        Union All Select 2
        Union All Select 3
        Union All Select 4
        Union All Select 5
        Union All Select 6
        Union All Select 7
        Union All Select 8          
        Union All Select 9
        Union All Select 10
        ) As Numbers
```

That said, the simplest way to solve problems where you need a sequential list of integers is to create a permanent Numbers or Tally table that contains this list. In this way, it will not matter how it was populated as it need only be populated once.

Answer (score 2):

```
select number  as n
from master..spt_values 
where type='p' 
and number between 0 and 10
```

Sorry I just noticed you were in MYSQL, this is MSSQL Only.

Comment: so there isn't a standard sql syntax to accomplish such a thing?

Comment: This just reads values from the SQL system table, I'm not familiar with MYSQL so the only thing I could suggest is you create a numbers table - I think many people do and use this.

Comment: The 'standard' way in MS SQL Server apparently applies to MySQL as well, judging from the question Matthew Flaschen referred you to, Number Sequence in MySQL.  Reading both questions, I'd say SPE109's answer is the best.  Create a 'utility' table.  In ms sql server, master.dbo.spt_values only has 0-2048 in it, and is 'yuck' a master table.  In my code, I create my own table that's always around, which is always populated and not messed with.  I refer to it like this: select n from numbers where n >=1 and n <= 10.  Same approach, guaranteed to work in MySQL.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable for that (although I'm not 100% clear on your requirements):

```
SELECT id, (@i := @i + 1) AS counter FROM <table>,
(SELECT @i := 0) AS vars WHERE @i <= 10;
```

You can include whatever other columns you like - I've just used `id` as an example. If the table from which you are selecting has at least 11 rows, this will work.  The parenthesised `SELECT` is executed first, and initialises the variable `@i` to zero.

Comment: sorry, im not familiar with variables.
please give me a simple view that contains values 0 to 10

Comment: If the idea of having a view to which you can join an existing table is purely to obtain a list of sequential numbers, then I think you are making things more difficult for yourself, whilst at the same time, involving a join where one is not needed. Can you edit your question to make your exact requirements clear?

Comment: Thats an elegant way to generate range

Answer (score -1):

Using pl sql we can do as follows

for i in 1..1000 loop

```
insert into a values(i,i*2);
```

end loop;

Is it helpful to solve your doubt?

Comment: sorry, i forgot. i want to have these values in a simple view to outer join it with a table that doesn't have all these values as ids, where i need all of them.
off course i can create a table and insert these values one by one, but i was curious that there may not need to create another table for such a simple thing.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Recursive CTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) to generate numbers from 1 to n.

```
with recursive cte as(
    select 1 as num
    union all
    select num + 1 from cte where num < 10
)

select num from cte;
```

**Output:**

```
num
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Comment: Probably because someone found this a good reason: "This answer is not useful (click again to undo)" ??