# Insert value into database 1000x times

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I would like to enter some value into database 1000x times.

Example:

```
      <?php
     $n = rand(1,30000);
    $n2 = $n."20";
for($i=1;$i=1000;$i++){
mysql_query("INSERT INTO reedem(5) VALUES ('".$n2."')");
}
?>
```

How could I do that correctly?

Comment: `"INSERT INTO reedem(columnName) VALUES ('1'), ('2'), ('3'), ...");`

Comment: But stop using the old, deprecated MySQL extension, switch to MySQLi or PDO with prepared statements/bind variables

Comment: And do you really have a column in your `redeem` table called `5`? Bad idea

Comment: @MarkBaker That number five means 5 percents ... I'll change it later

Comment: Mysql lets you have numbers for column names?I don`t think so.

Comment: @user3281364: "INTO reedem(5)"  the 5 is not possible there as far as I know. you need to have the name of the column there. If you put up example code here it should be functioning code (and if you use place holders you should make sure they make sense in as the code is useable/compileable with them)

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is incorrect:

```
for($i=1;$i=1000;$i++){
         ^^^^^^^
```

That should be `$i == 1000` - you're ASSIGNING `1000` to $i, and turning this into an infinite loop - since `$i = 1000 will ALWAYS be a "true" value, the loop never ends.

And your INSERT query is incorrect:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO reedem(5) VALUES ('".$n2."')");
                                ^---
```

A field cannot be named with just a number, unless it's escaped:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO reedem(`5`) VALUES ('".$n2."')");
                                ^-^---
```

and even then it's still not a good idea to do so.

Comment: And then, the query will be inserted zero times, because $i==1000 won't hold after $i=1. $i<1000 would be the way to go.

Comment: uh, yes it would. `$i =1` is the initial value at the first loop iteration. then it gets pegged to 1000 and never changes again. `$n2` would never change, since it's set outside the loop, but that one `$n2` would get inserted until the end of time.

Answer (score 0):

Prepared statements are useful when you need to run the same query multiple times.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'world');
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO redeem (myColumnName) VALUES (?)");
$n = rand(1,30000) . '20';
$stmt->bind_param("i",$n);

foreach(range(1,1000) as $i) {
    $stmt->execute();
}

$stmt->close();
```

if you want to insert 1000 different random values (as opposed to the same random value 1000 times) move the code that defines `$n` inside the loop

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'world');
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO redeem (myColumnName) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bind_param("i",$n);

foreach(range(1,1000) as $i) {
    $n = rand(1,30000) . '20';
    $stmt->execute();
}

$stmt->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to insert a random value between 120 and 3000020 into a field of a table. You can do that with one update:

```
UPDATE table SET field = ROUND(30000*RAND()+20)
```

So you wouldn't need `INSERT` if the table rows already exist. The table could be `users`, for instance. If you really need to do inserts, and you cannot use updates, then you can do multiple inserts in one command:

```
INSERT INTO table (column) 
VALUES (ROUND(30000*RAND()+20)),
       (ROUND(30000*RAND()+20)),
       (ROUND(30000*RAND()+20)),
       (ROUND(30000*RAND()+20)),
       (ROUND(30000*RAND()+20)),
       (ROUND(30000*RAND()+20)),
       (ROUND(30000*RAND()+20)),
       (ROUND(30000*RAND()+20)),
       (ROUND(30000*RAND()+20)),
       (ROUND(30000*RAND()+20));
```

So with 10 inserts you only need to loop a 100 times, which will be a lot quicker.

As others have said, you shouldn't use the mysql extension anymore. Go to mysqli or PDO. Prepared statements can also help to make things more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to insert many identical values, you can use *insert-select*, where *select* selects 1000 rows. You could use a table with 1000 rows, or a larger table from which you select the first 1000 rows, or you can generate 1000 rows on the fly using *connect by* as in:

```
select level
from dual
connect by level <= 100
;
```

This gives you 100 rows with one column, whose values are the numbers 1 .. 100. (This is oracle syntax, for an equivalent way of doing this in mySql see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701444/how-do-i-make-a-row-generator-in-mysql).).

So to insert 1000 rows with a value of 42 into a column xxx.x you'd go

```
insert into xxx (
    select 42 
    from (
        select level
        from dual
        connect by level <= 100
    )
);
```