# Translate Oracle Hierarchical Query to MySQL

Tags: mysql, oracle

```
select to_char(
         (to_date(20160218, 'yyyymmdd') + (level - 1) / 24),
         'yyyymmddhh24'
       ) dt
from dual
connect by level <= 24
```

This SQL can run in Oracle but MySQL does not support these hierarchical functions (`connect by level`).

How can it be translated to MySQL?

Comment: This is generating the fixed values '2016021800' to '2016021823'. Is this really what you need? No variable date, like sysdate or a date column to be used?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do the Recursive SELECT query in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16513418/how-to-do-the-recursive-select-query-in-mysql)

Comment: Or a better duplicate: [How do I make a row generator in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701444/how-do-i-make-a-row-generator-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need a recursive query in order to generate 24 values. You can use `UNION ALL` instead:

```
select '2016021800' as dt
union all
select '2016021801' as dt
union all
...
union all
select '2016021823' as dt;
```

The same is also possible with a variable date, such as the current date:

```
select date_format(curdate(), '%Y%m%d') || '01'
union all
select date_format(curdate(), '%Y%m%d') || '02'
union all
...
union all
select date_format(curdate(), '%Y%m%d') || '23';
```