# shell script to print a list of all half hour chunks for a given date

Tags: mysql, shell

I would like to generate below list for any given date to pass in a MySQL query.

Example : given date is "2018-08-28"

I need the output as

```
between '2018-08-28 00:00:00' and '2018-08-28 00:29:59'
between '2018-08-28 00:30:00' and '2018-08-28 00:59:59'
between '2018-08-28 1:00:00' and '2018-08-28 1:29:59'
between '2018-08-28 1:30:00' and '2018-08-28 1:59:59'
-
-
-
-

between '2018-08-28 23:00:00' and '2018-08-28 23:29:59'
between '2018-08-28 23:30:00' and '2018-08-28 23:59:59'
```

Comment: Is the above the _literal_ output you need?  If not, then what do you need?

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701444/how-do-i-make-a-row-generator-in-mysql then generate 48 numbered rows, then add (rownumber * 30) minutes to your date, then use a bit of string concat to build your results

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes above is the output I need. It has to be for all the hours(0-23)

Comment: Or do it in excel (easier) and paste it in (I assume you're looking for an easy way to write a case when).  If yoire trying to produce a report of a day cut into half hour blocks and eg a count of the number of events in that block, the query would be different, post the actual problem you're trying to solve

Comment: MySQL is for the storage and retrieval of data. Do other stuff elsewhere.

Comment: what time is thirty o'clock

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @dtStart AS DATETIME ='20180828 00:00:00' 
        ,@dtEnd AS DATETIME = '20180828 23:59:59'
        ,@iInterval AS INT = 30;  --30 min interval


WITH aCTE
AS(
    SELECT 
        @dtStart AS StartDateTime,
        DATEADD(MINUTE,@iInterval,@dtStart) AS EndDateTime
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        DATEADD(MINUTE,@iInterval,StartDateTime),
        DATEADD(MINUTE,@iInterval,EndDateTime)
    FROM aCTE
    WHERE
        DATEADD(MINUTE,@iInterval,EndDateTime) <= @dtEnd
)

SELECT 

    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),StartDateTime,108) 
    + ' ' + RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), StartDateTime, 9), 2) 
    + ' - ' +

    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),EndDateTime,108) 
    + ' ' + RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), EndDateTime, 9), 2) AS Result
FROM aCTE
```

Try this and revert me if you find any issue.