# How to get a list of years from start year and end year

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table with:

```
id --- name --- start_year --- end_year

1 --- george --- 2005 --- 2009
```

How do I get with a mysql query the year between this to years like:

```
2005
2006
2007
2008
2009
```

?

Comment: are those row or fields (the years you used for the example)?

Comment: Google for a MySQL row generator and generate a list of numbers from eg 1000 to 4000 then join the list to your table `ON list.num BETWEEN start_year AND end_year`

Comment: You can checkout this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186756/generating-a-range-of-numbers-in-mysql

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in the presentation layer/application-level code, assuming you have that (e.g. a simple PHP loop acting upon an ordered array).

Answer (score 1):

Using any one of the answers [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701444/how-do-i-make-a-row-generator-in-mysql) that you like the look of, generate a list of numbers from eg 1000 to 4000

When you do

```
SELECT * FROM rowgen
```

You should see a list of numbers:

```
num
1000
1001
1002
...
3999
4000
```

Or whatever range will be acceptable for your dates. Maybe 2000 to 2050 will do. Anyway... then you just join the list to your table `ON rowgen.num BETWEEN start_year AND end_year`

```
SELECT *
FROM
  yourtable t
  INNER JOIN
  rowgen r
  ON r.num BETWEEN t.start_year AND t.end_year
```

You'll get:

```
1, George, 2005, 2009, 2005
1, George, 2005, 2009, 2006
1, George, 2005, 2009, 2007
1, George, 2005, 2009, 2008
1, George, 2005, 2009, 2009
```

The last column being the generated row numbers