# How to get date increments in between start date and end date in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have sample dates in a table and what I need to get is each of the months  between the start date and end date.

sample :

```
 ID   Startdate    EndDate
 1   01-01-2019  01-03-2019
 2   01-08-2019  01-02-2020
```

I need to fetch months and year from these dates.

Desired output :

```
ID  Dates
1  January 2019
1  February 2019
1  March 2019
2  August 2019
2  September 2019
2  October 2019
2  November 2019
2  December 2019
2  January 2020
2  February 2020
```

How cah I achieve this in MySQL and how to do increment or any loop kind of operation. On the query side I'm not getting any idea to move on this.

Comment: What's your mysql version?

Comment: Check this thread on generating rows. --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701444/how-do-i-make-a-row-generator-in-mysql

Comment: Date sorted or ID sorted?

Comment: Are those dates or varchars? They're not in MySQL date format...

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: @Nick..if i want the same result in 2020-01-01,2020-02-01 etc what i need to modify in the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of ways to achieve this. The first will only work on MySQL 8+ and uses a recursive `CTE` to generate the months between `StartDate` and `EndDate`:

```
WITH RECURSIVE CTE AS (
  SELECT ID, Startdate AS d, EndDate
  FROM dates
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ID, d + INTERVAL 1 MONTH, EndDate
  FROM CTE
  WHERE d < EndDate
)
SELECT ID, DATE_FORMAT(d, '%M %Y') AS Dates
FROM CTE
ORDER BY ID, d
```

The second (which will run on any version of MySQL) uses a numbers table (in this case numbers from 0 to 99, allowing for a range of up to 99 months between `StartDate` and `EndDate`; if you need longer, adding more tables to the `CROSS JOIN` will increase that range by a factor of 10 for each table added) to generate the list of months difference, this is then `JOIN`ed to the original table so that the generated date `Startdate + INTERVAL n.n MONTH` is less than or equal to `EndDate`:

```
SELECT ID, DATE_FORMAT(Startdate + INTERVAL n.n MONTH, '%M %Y') AS Dates
FROM dates
JOIN (
  SELECT n10.n * 10 + n1.n * 1 AS n
  FROM (
    SELECT 0 n UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3
    UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6
    UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9
  ) n10
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 0 n UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3
    UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6
    UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9
  ) n1
) n ON Startdate + INTERVAL n.n MONTH <= EndDate
ORDER BY ID, Startdate + INTERVAL n.n MONTH
```

Having generated our list of dates, we format it using [`DATE_FORMAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) and a format string of `%M %Y`. For both queries the output is:

```
ID  Dates
1   January 2019
1   February 2019
1   March 2019
2   August 2019
2   September 2019
2   October 2019
2   November 2019
2   December 2019
2   January 2020
2   February 2020
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5tMDp56G79ePNhAgZZ5vxk/0)

Comment: perfect fit for my requirement

Comment: if i want the same result in 2020-01-01,2020-02-01 etc what i need to modify in the query @Nick

Comment: @mohan111 change `'%M %Y'` in the `DATE_FORMAT` to `'%Y-%m-%d'`

Comment: yes changed to the above mentioned format but it giving like  2019-January-1st,2019-February-1st etc;. I'm looking for yyyy-mm-dd (i.e 2019-01-01)

Comment: @mohan111 works fine for me: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5tMDp56G79ePNhAgZZ5vxk/1

Comment: yes @nick i have added capital letters %Y %M%D i have changed it ...thanks

Comment: @mohan111 Once again it looks like you have a good answer already...

Comment: can you please have a look : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61530970/how-to-fetch-records-based-on-the-dates-in-mysql?noredirect=1#comment108843802_61530970