# How to Fetch records based on the Dates in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, partition-by

I have sample data

```
 ID  Name  Amount  cal_amt Run_amt  Dates
 1   Test   15000    0.00  15000    2020-06-01
 1   Test   15000    0.00  30000    2020-04-01
 1   Test   15000    12000 30000    2020-05-01
 2   Test_1   18000   0.00  25000    2020-06-01
 2   Test_1   18000   0.00  35000    2020-04-01
 2   Test_1   18000   16000 35000    2020-05-01
```

I need to get MAX(month) of Run_Amount  i.e  : 2020-06-01 --> 15000

Need to fetch cal_amt of current month i.e   : 2020-05-01 --> 12000 and  0.00 also relates to this month 2020-04-01

I need to get output like this :

```
 ID  Name  Amount  cal_amt Run_amt  
 1   Test   15000    12000  15000 
 2   Test_1 18000    16000  25000
```

It is sample data but have another few more columns  are there  I have tried with **MAX() conditions**  and

```
ROW_NUMBER()over (PARTITION BY run_amt order by Date )
```

Can anyone suggest me the best way

Comment: Can you clarify - you want the value of `Run_amt` from the latest `Date`, and the value of `cal_amt` from the current month, but what about the values for `ID`, `Name` and `Amount`? where should they come from?

Comment: @Nick yes you are  right  . ID,Name and Amount are there in the same table  I can get them by using GROUP BY .I'm looking for  Run_amt and cal_amt

Comment: You don't have enough sample data in the query to be clear as to how to select the output values. Please add some more with different `ID`, `Name` and `Amount` values...

Comment: @Nick sure Adding

Comment: @Nick I have added sample Data

Comment: Your requirement is still unclear. Explain why do you need in the results a row like `1   Test   15000    12000  15000` for each of its elements.

Comment: @forpas Sure  12000 = cal_amt for current month(may) and 15000 for  MAX(month) i.e June and  rest of all ID,Test and Amount  i will get those

Comment: This question is all over the place `I need to get MAX(month) of Run_Amount i.e : 2020-05-01 --> 15000` BUT 2020-05-01 is not june and it is not the max(month). Did you mean 2020-06-01 in your question? Also, why don't you want this record: `2   Test_1   18000   0.00  25000    2020-06-01`. It's the max(month) too?

Comment: @JNevill editing the question yesterday I have posted so it's  April and today it is may I'm changing

Comment: @JNevill I have edited please you can check now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function to get the row with the `Run_amt` of the max month and then with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT t.ID, t.Name, t.Amount,
  MAX(CASE WHEN LAST_DAY(Date) = LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE) THEN cal_amt END) cal_amt,
  MAX(CASE WHEN t.rn = 1 THEN Run_amt END) Run_amt
FROM (
  SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Name, Amount ORDER BY Date DESC) rn
  FROM tablename
) t
GROUP BY t.ID, t.Name, t.Amount
```

Or:

```
SELECT t.ID, t.Name, t.Amount,
       MAX(t.cal_amt) cal_amt,
       MAX(t.Run_amt) Run_amt
FROM (
  SELECT ID, Name, Amount,
    MAX(CASE WHEN LAST_DAY(Date) = LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE) THEN cal_amt END) 
      OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Name, Amount ORDER BY Date DESC) cal_amt,
    FIRST_VALUE(Run_amt) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Name, Amount ORDER BY Date DESC) Run_amt
  FROM tablename
) t  
GROUP BY t.ID, t.Name, t.Amount
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ec9945cf261202aec16c9f8a6b060913).
Results:

```
> ID | Name   | Amount | cal_amt | Run_amt
> -: | :----- | -----: | ------: | ------:
>  1 | Test   |  15000 |   12000 |   15000
>  2 | Test_1 |  18000 |   16000 |   25000
```