# calculate column names automatically sql

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there a way to calculate column names automatically in SQL like below. I need top calculate the Calendar weeks based on from and to date and distribute evenly

| Material | From | To | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| M01 | 03.10.2022 | 31.10.2022 | 1000 |
| M02 | 14.11.2022 | 28.11.2022 | 1000 |

**Expected output**

CW =calendar week

| Material | Cw40 | CW41 | Cw42 | CW43 | CW44 | CW45 | CW46 | CW47 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| M01 | 250 | 250 | 250 | 250 |  |  |  |  |
| M02 |  |  |  |  |  |  | 500 | 500 |

Comment: What is your actual issue? Distribution? Dynamic column names? Calculation of calendar week?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to calculate column names automatically in SQL like below.

No, in SQL (not just Oracle SQL) you needs a fixed, known number of column names so it is impossible to dynamically generate columns with a static SQL query.

---

If you want to generate the data then either:

Generate the data as rows (rather than columns) and pivot the result in whatever third-party application you are using to access the database. You can generate the output using a correlated row-generator:

```
SELECT t.material,
       w.iso_year,
       w.iso_week,
       w.weekly_sales
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS APPLY (
         SELECT TO_NUMBER(
                  TO_CHAR(
                    TRUNC(from_dt, 'IW') + INTERVAL '7' DAY * (LEVEL - 1),
                    'IYYY'
                  )
                ) AS iso_year,
                TO_NUMBER(
                  TO_CHAR(
                    TRUNC(from_dt, 'IW') + INTERVAL '7' DAY * (LEVEL - 1),
                    'IW'
                  )
                ) AS iso_week,
                ( LEAST(
                    TRUNC(from_dt, 'IW') + INTERVAL '7' DAY * LEVEL,
                    to_dt
                  )
                  - GREATEST(
                    TRUNC(from_dt, 'IW') + INTERVAL '7' DAY * (LEVEL - 1),
                    from_dt
                  )
                ) / (to_dt - from_dt) * sales AS weekly_sales
         FROM   DUAL
         CONNECT BY TRUNC(from_dt, 'IW') + INTERVAL '7' DAY * (LEVEL-1) < to_dt
       ) w
```

or:

```sql
WITH data (from_dt, dt, to_dt, material, sales) AS (
  SELECT from_dt, from_dt, to_dt, material, sales
  FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT from_dt,
         TRUNC(dt + INTERVAL '7' DAY, 'IW'),
         to_dt,
         material,
         sales
  FROM   data
  WHERE  TRUNC(dt + INTERVAL '7' DAY, 'IW') < to_dt
)
SELECT material,
       TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(dt, 'IYYY')) AS iso_year,
       TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(dt, 'IW')) AS iso_week,
       ( LEAST(dt + INTERVAL '7' DAY, to_dt) - dt)
         / (to_dt - from_dt) * sales AS weekly_sales
FROM   data
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (Material, From_dt, To_dt, Sales) AS
SELECT 'M01', DATE '2022-10-03', DATE '2022-10-31', 1000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'M02', DATE '2022-11-14', DATE '2022-11-28', 1000 FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

| MATERIAL | ISO_YEAR | ISO_WEEK | WEEKLY_SALES |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| M01 | 2022 | 40 | 250 |
| M01 | 2022 | 41 | 250 |
| M01 | 2022 | 42 | 250 |
| M01 | 2022 | 43 | 250 |
| M02 | 2022 | 46 | 500 |
| M02 | 2022 | 47 | 500 |

Or, if you did want to output the values as columns then you need to specify the columns (which would be 53 columns for all 53 potential ISO weeks) and can do that using:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.material,
         w.iso_year,
         w.iso_week,
         w.weekly_sales
  FROM   table_name t
         CROSS APPLY (
           SELECT TO_NUMBER(
                    TO_CHAR(
                      TRUNC(from_dt, 'IW') + INTERVAL '7' DAY * (LEVEL - 1),
                      'IYYY'
                    )
                  ) AS iso_year,
                  TO_NUMBER(
                    TO_CHAR(
                      TRUNC(from_dt, 'IW') + INTERVAL '7' DAY * (LEVEL - 1),
                      'IW'
                    )
                  ) AS iso_week,
                  ( LEAST(
                      TRUNC(from_dt, 'IW') + INTERVAL '7' DAY * LEVEL,
                      to_dt
                    )
                    - GREATEST(
                      TRUNC(from_dt, 'IW') + INTERVAL '7' DAY * (LEVEL - 1),
                      from_dt
                    )
                  ) / (to_dt - from_dt) * sales AS weekly_sales
           FROM   DUAL
           CONNECT BY TRUNC(from_dt, 'IW') + INTERVAL '7' DAY * (LEVEL-1) < to_dt
         ) w
)
PIVOT (
  SUM(weekly_sales)
  FOR iso_week IN (
     1 AS cw01,
     2 AS cw02,
     3 AS cw03,
    -- ...
    40 AS cw40,
    41 AS cw41,
    42 AS cw42,
    43 AS cw43,
    44 AS cw44,
    45 AS cw45,
    46 AS cw46,
    47 AS cw47,
    48 AS cw48,
    49 AS cw49,
    50 AS cw50,
    51 AS cw51,
    52 AS cw52,
    53 AS cw53
  )
)
```

or:

```sql
WITH data (from_dt, dt, to_dt, material, sales) AS (
  SELECT from_dt, from_dt, to_dt, material, sales
  FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT from_dt,
         TRUNC(dt + INTERVAL '7' DAY, 'IW'),
         to_dt,
         material,
         sales
  FROM   data
  WHERE  TRUNC(dt + INTERVAL '7' DAY, 'IW') < to_dt
)
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT material,
         TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(dt, 'IYYY')) AS iso_year,
         TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(dt, 'IW')) AS iso_week,
         ( LEAST(dt + INTERVAL '7' DAY, to_dt) - dt)
           / (to_dt - from_dt) * sales AS weekly_sales
  FROM   data
)
PIVOT (
  SUM(weekly_sales)
  FOR iso_week IN (
     1 AS cw01,
     2 AS cw02,
     3 AS cw03,
    -- ...
    40 AS cw40,
    41 AS cw41,
    42 AS cw42,
    43 AS cw43,
    44 AS cw44,
    45 AS cw45,
    46 AS cw46,
    47 AS cw47,
    48 AS cw48,
    49 AS cw49,
    50 AS cw50,
    51 AS cw51,
    52 AS cw52,
    53 AS cw53
  )
)
```

Which both output:

| MATERIAL | ISO_YEAR | CW01 | CW02 | CW03 | CW40 | CW41 | CW42 | CW43 | CW44 | CW45 | CW46 | CW47 | CW48 | CW49 | CW50 | CW51 | CW52 | CW53 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| M01 | 2022 | *null* | *null* | *null* | 250 | 250 | 250 | 250 | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* |
| M02 | 2022 | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | 500 | 500 | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/QfT6W9S6)

Comment: anyway to do it without using  connect by ?

Comment: @Steve You can try a recursive sub-query factoring clause (recursive `WITH` clause) or else use `SELECT ... UNION ALL SELECT ... UNION ALL ...` with 52 `UNION ALL`s?

Comment: thanks, but how with recursive WITH clause, (atleast the first part - without transposing)

Comment: Anyother way to do it without using recursive/connectby, so that it works it all in database

Comment: @Steve All RDBMS have slightly different syntaxes; you can use recursive `WITH` clauses in many databases so that is probably likely to be the most portable way to write the query however you are very unlikely to find one query that will run on every RDBMS as, amongst other things, they will all have different names for their functions.

Comment: anychance to do with window function , working with mysql older version so

Comment: @Steve [Ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and tag it with MySQL (and not Oracle) if you are using MySQL (and not Oracle) and then you might get an answer about the correct technology.

Comment: @Steve Or search the internet for "MySQL row generator" (and you'll probably end up at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701444/how-do-i-make-a-row-generator-in-mysql))